# Group controls offset when rotated fabric.js

Tags: javascript, rotation, fabricjs

I've created a fabric custom class "VectorPlaceholder" that is basically a group that contains a Rectangle and a Vector:

```
// Fabric.js custom vector EPS object
fabric.VectorPlaceholder = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Group, {
    async: true,
    type: 'vector-placeholder',
    lockUniScalingWithSkew: false,
    noScaleCache: true,


    initialize: function (options) {                

        boundsRectangle = new fabric.Rect({            
            strokeDashArray: [10,10],
            originX: 'center',
            originY: 'center',
            stroke: '#000000',
            strokeWidth: 1,
            width: options.width || 300,
            height: options.height || 300,
            fill: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',            
        });

        this.setControlsVisibility({            
            ml: false,
            mb: false,
            mr: false,
            mt: false,            
        });

        this.originX = 'center',
        this.originY = 'center',

        this.callSuper('initialize', [boundsRectangle], options);

    },

    setVector: function (vector) {        
        //We remove any EPS that was in that position
        var EPSGroup = this;
        EPSGroup.forEachObject(function (object) {
            if (object && object.type != "rect") {
                EPSGroup.remove(object);
            }
        });

        var scale = 1;        
        var xOffset = EPSGroup.getScaledWidth() / 2;
        var yOffset = EPSGroup.getScaledHeight() / 2;
        if (vector.height > vector.width) {            
            scale = EPSGroup.getScaledHeight() / vector.height;
            xOffset = xOffset - (EPSGroup.getScaledWidth() - vector.width * scale) / 2

        }
        else {
            scale = EPSGroup.getScaledWidth() / vector.width;
            yOffset = yOffset - (EPSGroup.getScaledHeight() - vector.height * scale) / 2

        }

        vector.left = EPSGroup.left - xOffset;
        vector.top = EPSGroup.top - yOffset;        
        vector.set('scaleY', scale);
        vector.set('scaleX', scale);
        var angle = 0;        
        if (EPSGroup.get('angle')) {
            angle = EPSGroup.get('angle');
            vector.setAngle(angle);                        
        }        
        EPSGroup.addWithUpdate(vector);
        EPSGroup.setCoords();      
    },

});
```

The idea of this class is to have a placeholder where users can upload SVGs.
This is done by calling to fabric.loadSVGFromString and then passing the result to the function in my custom class (setVector)

```
fabric.loadSVGFromString(svgString, function(objects, options) {
   // Group the SVG objects to make a single element
   var a = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
   var EPSGroup = new fabric.VectorPlaceholder({});
   EPSGroup.setVector(a);
```

This works perfectly when I create my custom object and don't rotate it. As you can see the group controls are aligned with the dashed rectangle.

[image]

The problem is when I create an empty VectorPlaceholder and I rotate it manually. After the manual rotation, when setVector is called this is what happens:

[image]

I can't understand why the group controls ignore the rotation, what I'm doing wrong? How can I make the group controls render aligned with the rotated rectangle?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the angle after you make `setVector` method
http://jsfiddle.net/2segrwx0/1/

```js
// Fabric.js custom vector EPS object
fabric.VectorPlaceholder = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Group, {
    async: true,
    type: 'vector-placeholder',
    lockUniScalingWithSkew: false,
    noScaleCache: true,


    initialize: function (options) {                

        boundsRectangle = new fabric.Rect({            
            strokeDashArray: [10,10],
            originX: 'center',
            originY: 'center',
            stroke: '#000000',
            strokeWidth: 1,
            width: options.width || 300,
            height: options.height || 300,
            fill: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',            
        });

        this.setControlsVisibility({            
            ml: false,
            mb: false,
            mr: false,
            mt: false,            
        });

        this.originX = 'center',
        this.originY = 'center',

        this.callSuper('initialize', [boundsRectangle], options);

    },

    setVector: function (vector) {        
        //We remove any EPS that was in that position
        var EPSGroup = this;
        EPSGroup.forEachObject(function (object) {
            if (object && object.type != "rect") {
                EPSGroup.remove(object);
            }
        });

        var scale = 1;        
        var xOffset = EPSGroup.getScaledWidth() / 2;
        var yOffset = EPSGroup.getScaledHeight() / 2;
        if (vector.height > vector.width) {            
            scale = EPSGroup.getScaledHeight() / vector.height;
            xOffset = xOffset - (EPSGroup.getScaledWidth() - vector.width * scale) / 2

        }
        else {
            scale = EPSGroup.getScaledWidth() / vector.width;
            yOffset = yOffset - (EPSGroup.getScaledHeight() - vector.height * scale) / 2

        }

        vector.left = EPSGroup.left - xOffset;
        vector.top = EPSGroup.top - yOffset;        
        vector.set('scaleY', scale);
        vector.set('scaleX', scale);
        /*var angle = 0;        
        if (EPSGroup.get('angle')) {
            angle = EPSGroup.get('angle');
            vector.setAngle(angle);                        
        }       */ 
        EPSGroup.addWithUpdate(vector);
        EPSGroup.setCoords();      
    },

});

 canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', {
 
});


fabric.loadSVGFromString('<svg height="210" width="500"><polygon points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198" style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:nonzero;" /></svg>', function(objects, options) {
   // Group the SVG objects to make a single element
   var a = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
   var EPSGroup = new fabric.VectorPlaceholder({});
   EPSGroup.left=200;
   EPSGroup.top=200;

   EPSGroup.setVector(a);  
    EPSGroup.angle=45;
   canvas.add(EPSGroup);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.5/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width=500 height=300 ></canvas>
```